# How to change font size in sweet alert dialog Library

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, sweetalert

I'm using [sweet alert dialog](https://github.com/leogiroux/sweet-alert-dialog) Library to show alert dialog, but I can't change font size in alert messages how to change `.setTitleText()` or `.setContentText()`... text method size?

Comment: Nobody found an answer to this?

Comment: Looks like there is no option to change the text size. One thing you can do is add the library to your project and add your own custom method to change the text size

Answer (score 0):

You have to override it:

```
public class SweetAlertDialog2 extends SweetAlertDialog {

    public SweetAlertDialogMulti(Context context, int alertType) {
        super(context, alertType);

        this.setOnShowListener(dialog -> {
            SweetAlertDialog alertDialog = (SweetAlertDialog) dialog;
            TextView text = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.content_text);
            text.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_END);
            text.setLines(7);
            text.setTypeface(tf)
        });
    }
}
```